# Allow FTP and Database on single IP address

Tags: mysql, ftp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server, and i use this in the lab with local ip address (192.168.0.1) and configured with live IP too (144.12.65.2 this is a static IP)
so, i want to allow users to access the FTP and database service only from lab not from outside. Please help me.

Comment: There are multiple (very basic) solutions to that, such as a firewall, binding services to a specific ip-addresses, TCP wrappers etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a firewall to do that. First, install `ufw` on your server:
`sudo apt install ufw`

Then, deny incoming requests by default:
`sudo ufw default deny incoming`

After that you will want to allow reuests from your lab on every port:
`sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24`

Now reload and enable the firewall with the following commands:
`sudo ufw reload`
`sudo ufw enable`

To allow access to a TCP port (in this example port 21) from everywhere (that means from the outside network), run this:
`sudo ufw allow 21/tcp`

To deny it again (delete the rule) run this:
`sudo ufw delete allow 21/tcp`

DON'T run `sudo ufw deny 21/tcp` because it will also block access from your local net.

Always reload ufw after a change with this command:
`sudo ufw reload`

There are also other solutions (like editing the configs of the respective programs), but I think this is the easiest one.